# Proguard with JDK 10 / JDK 11 and maven pugin

Tags: maven, proguard, java-10, java-11

Ho do I run Proguard with JDK 10 / JDK 11 and setup maven plugin?

[Migration issues concerning OpenJDK 11 & OpenJFX 11 (& Proguard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115075/migration-issues-concerning-openjdk-11-openjfx-11-proguard)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Proguard 6.0.3 does not run on Java 11 yet
(#188 Support Java 11, see https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/188/).

Your sources can be compiled with JDK 11. For proguard plugin we have to use JDK 10.

In maven-compiler-plugin, set version to JDK 10:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
         <source>10</source>
         <target>10</target>
         <compilerArgs>
             <arg>--add-modules=[required modules]</arg>
         </compilerArgs>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Property for JDK 10 (OpenJDK is fine):

```
<properties>
    <java.home.openjdk10>[pathtoJDK20]\jdk-10.0.2</java.home.openjdk10>
</properties>
```

proguard-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.dingxin</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process-classes-with-proguard</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <options>
                    <option>[proguarg options]</option>
                </options>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/lib/jrt-fs.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.base.jmod(!.jar;!module-info.class)</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.compiler.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.corba.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.datatransfer.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.desktop.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.instrument.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.logging.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.management.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.management.rmi.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.naming.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.prefs.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.rmi.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.scripting.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.se.ee.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.se.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.security.jgss.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.security.sasl.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.smartcardio.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.sql.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.sql.rowset.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.transaction.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.xml.bind.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.xml.crypto.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.xml.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.xml.ws.annotation.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/java.xml.ws.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.accessibility.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.aot.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.attach.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.charsets.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.compiler.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.crypto.cryptoki.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.crypto.ec.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.crypto.mscapi.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.dynalink.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.editpad.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.hotspot.agent.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.httpserver.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.incubator.httpclient.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.internal.ed.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.internal.jvmstat.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.internal.le.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.internal.opt.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.internal.vm.ci.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.internal.vm.compiler.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jartool.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.javadoc.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jcmd.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jconsole.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jdeps.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jdi.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jdwp.agent.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jlink.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jshell.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jsobject.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.jstatd.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.localedata.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.management.agent.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.management.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.naming.dns.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.naming.rmi.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.net.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.pack.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.rmic.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.scripting.nashorn.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.sctp.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.security.auth.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.security.jgss.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.unsupported.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.xml.bind.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.xml.dom.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.xml.ws.jmod</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home.openjdk10}/jmods/jdk.zipfs.jmod</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: In maven-compiler-plugin you should use `<release>10</release>` instead of source/target. Furthermore if you need modules you should simply add `module-info.java` file in `src/main/java`....Is this really the way to go for the proguard-maven-plugin? It should be changed to handle modules in a better way...